# Link/event to another report in sql server reporting services 2004

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hi all and thanks in advance.
Is there a way to provide a link from one .rdl to another details report. I'm using .net 1.1 and I believe it's the first version of SSRS.

Comment: Reporting Services 2000. (2000 > 2005 > 2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, a SSRS report can link directly to another report via a URL.

The following article discusses the variouse types of navigation that you can use within a a sql server report.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964132(SQL.90).aspx#rsrptnvdrldn05